# rmtp server for .net

Tags: c#, .net, flash, chat

Hi
i'm creating a chat application on flash and i want to use c#.net on server side. Can someone recommend good rmtp server for my purpose? I look at Weborb (it is not free) and FluorineFx.NET(it has pure documentation and i have some problems with that library). I'm student, is it real to free use any proprietary server ?

Comment: maybe if you share and ask about your problems with FluorineFx.NET we could help

Answer (score 0):

For a free opensource rmtp server try C++ RMTP Server:

> http://www.rtmpd.com/

Let me know your results with this.